# SSL_accept hangs after calling fork()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, posix, openssl

I'm writing an app in C++ using openssl, and I can't seem to get the ssl socket connection to work.

I have an abstract class, with multiple functions implemented using various protocols by the inheriting classes and simple TCP and UDP ( posix sockets ) work fine.

I could not get the ssl working though and after some code browsing and tweaking I found out, that it is the fork() function which causes problems.

I wrote a very simple program to check things out, and this is what I get:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include </usr/local/include/ssl/ssl.h>

#include "SSL_CA.cpp"

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

    int retval;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *con;
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    socklen_t client_len;
    int max_clients = 40;
    int serv_sock, client_sock;

    if ( ( serv_sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0 )
                return -12; 

    SSL_library_init();
    int SSL_CA = NowySSL();
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = port;

cout << "Conf " << endl;

    if ( bind( serv_sock, ( sockaddr * ) &serv_addr, sizeof( serv_addr ) ) < 0 )
        return -1;

    if ( listen( serv_sock, max_clients ) < 0 )
        return -1;


    while (1) {

        cout << "Waiting" << endl;

        if ( ( client_sock = accept( serv_sock, ( sockaddr * ) &client_addr, &client_len ) ) < 0 )
            return -1;

        pid_t pid = fork();

        if ( pid = 0 ) {

            con = NULL;
            ctx = NULL;
            ctx = (SSL_CTX *)SSL_CTX_new( SSLv23_server_method() );
            con = (SSL *)SSL_new( (SSL_CTX *)ctx );

            if (
                !( ( ( !SSL_CA ) && ( SSL_NO_CA_RUN( con, ctx, client_sock, 0 ) ) ) ||
                ( ( SSL_CA ) && ( SSL_CA_RUN( con, ctx, client_sock, true ) ) ) )
            )
                return -1;

            char buf[10];

            if ( ( retval = SSL_read( con, buf, 10  ) ) <= 0 )
                return -16; 
            cout << "Got msg " << buf << " " << retval << endl;

            sprintf(buf, "12345" );

            if ( ( retval = SSL_write( con, buf, strlen(buf) ) ) <= 0 )
                return -1; 

            cout << "Sent" << endl;

        }
        else cout << "Parent " << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

These are the SSL_CA_RUN and SSL_NO_CA_RUN functions -  not written by me, but i have to use it

```
int SSL_NO_CA_RUN (SSL *con, SSL_CTX *ctx, int msgsock, int exit_now)
{
//   printf ("SSL NO CA\n");
//   SSL_library_init();
//   ctx=(SSL_CTX *)SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
//   con=(SSL *)SSL_new((SSL_CTX *)ctx);
   if ((!SSL_set_fd (con,msgsock))||
      (!SSL_use_RSAPrivateKey_file (con,"ktsa_u_linux.k",1))||
      (!SSL_use_certificate_file (con,"ktsa_u_linux.c",1))||
      (!SSL_accept (con))) 
       {
        printf ("SSL ERROR (%s)\n",strerror(errno));
        if (exit_now)
     {     
           zamknij_polaczenie (con,ctx,msgsock);
           exit(0);
     } 
    return false;  
       }
  // printf ("SSL NO CA OK!!!\n");
   return true;       
}


int SSL_CA_RUN (SSL *con, SSL_CTX *ctx, int msgsock, int exit_now)
{
    int ret, ok=true;
    X509 *peer;
    FILE *fp;
    char error[250];
//   printf ("SSL CA\n");

//MARCIN (START)
                //robimy linki do certyfikatow  Marcin
                 certhash(CA_DIR,CRL_DIR,getpid());
                //dostep_read (890);
//          SSL_library_init();

//      printf("\n");

//                ctx=(SSL_CTX *)SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());

//          con=(SSL *)SSL_new((SSL_CTX *)ctx);
            cb=pem_passwd_cb;           
        SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ctx,haslo);
        SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx,cb);
        //SSL_set_verify_depth(con,10); default  = 9
        SSL_set_verify(con,SSL_VERIFY_PEER|SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,NULL);
                //      SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER|SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,NULL);

                //SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,"SHA1+3DES:+RSA:HIGH");
                //SSL_set_cipher_list(con,"SHA1+3DES:+RSA:HIGH");
                if ((!SSL_set_fd (con,msgsock))||
            (!SSL_use_RSAPrivateKey_file (con,KEY_FILE,1))||
            (!SSL_use_certificate_file (con,CERT_FILE,1))||
//          (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CA_FILE,NULL))||
            (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,NULL,linkdir))||
            (!SSL_accept (con))
                     )
                        {
              if (exit_now)
               {
                             remove_symdir(getpid());       
//               printf("error connect\n");         
                             zamknij_polaczenie (con,ctx,msgsock);
                 exit(0);
               } else remove_symdir(getpid());          
              ok=false;     
            } 
         if (ok)
          { 
             peer=SSL_get_peer_certificate(con); 
             if(peer!=NULL)
                 {
                 //ret=1 - odwolany
             //ret=0 - wszystko ok
             //ret = inne - jakis inny blad, np. brak wlasciwej listy crl
                 //ret=check_peer_crl_dir(peer,error,CRL_DIR);  //sprawdzenie odwolania certyfikatu przychodzacego
                 ret=check_peera(peer,error,0);  //sprawdzenie odwolania certyfikatu przychodzacego
//                   printf("peer certyfikat:%s:%i\n",error,ret);
                 }
         if ((peer==NULL)||(ret==1))
              {
              //nie akceptujemy polaczenia bo nie dostalismy certyfikatu lub certyfikat jest odwolany
//          printf("polaczenie odrzucone - certyfikat peera odwolany, brak certyfikatu lub wystawiony przez inne CA \n");           
            if (exit_now)
             {
              remove_symdir(getpid());          
                          zamknij_polaczenie (con,ctx,msgsock);
                          exit(2);
             }
            ok=false;
              }
          }      
         if (ok)
          { 
                    X509_free(peer);   //potrzebne?
                    peer=NULL;

            //mozna sprawdzic tez nasz certyfikat
            if (!(fp = fopen (CERT_FILE, "r")))  //"/router/ssl/cert/sslcert.cer"
                  printf ("Error reading my certificate file\n");
            if (!(peer = PEM_read_X509 (fp, NULL, NULL, NULL)))
              printf ("Error reading my certificate in file\n");
            if (fp)fclose (fp);

            if(peer!=NULL)
                 { 
                 //ret=1 - odwolany
             //ret=0 - wszystko ok
             //ret = inne - jakis inny blad, np. brak wlasciwej listy crl
                 //ret=check_peer_crl_dir(peer,error,CRL_DIR);  //sprawdzenie odwolania certyfikatu przychodzacego
                 ret=check_peera(peer,error,0);  //sprawdzenie odwolania certyfikatu naszego
  //                 printf("nasz certyfikat:%s:%i\n",error,ret);
                 }

             if ((peer==NULL)||(ret==1))
              {
              //nie akceptujemy polaczenia bo nasz certyfikat ma problem lub jest odwolany
//            printf("polaczenie odrzucone- nasz certyfikat odwolany\n");           
            if (exit_now)
             {  
               remove_symdir(getpid());         
                       zamknij_polaczenie (con,ctx,msgsock);
                       exit(2);
             }  
            ok=false;
              }
           }      
         if (ok)
          {  
                X509_free(peer);   //potrzebne?
                    peer=NULL;
          }          
//               printf("connected...ok\n");
   remove_symdir(getpid());         
   return ok;
}
```

If I don't call fork, all works fine, the message gets through, if the fork's there it gets stuck on ssl_accept.

Any help?

Comment: See Duck's answer below, pid = 0 is an assignment operation.  You most likely meant to do pid == 0.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is just a typo or your real problem but this isn't going to do what you intend:

```
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if ( pid = 0 )
    {
       con = NULL;
       //.............
```

Your child code is not going to execute.